# Suckers on rose bushes

Tags: diagnosis, suckers

It looks like I have a bunch of suckers on this rose bush.

You can see how they look different from the branch with the true bud. The fat red-leafed branches don’t seem to have any buds at the ends.  They’re not coming from the ground or the bottom of the plant, but from an established branch. (I did pinch off a few budding branches as they came out of dormancy to keep it from being overcrowded as I always have a problem with powdery mildew.) I’m just wondering, if they are suckers, why are there so many?

[image]

Comment: Please add a picture showing a closeup of the bottom of the plant. It would also help if you know the variety of rose.

Comment: It’s a Queen Mary 2.

Comment: They're not suckers - there appears to be one very thick strong lateral stem, much thicker than all the other stems. Also a stem that's  either dead or white or is that a trick of the light... The colour of the foliage isn't important, its common for new growth on roses to start out red. The question for me is, is that stem flattened at all, or completely round? Is there a pale or dead bit of stem too?When was the last time you gave it any fertiliser and how often do  you usually fertilise, if you do at all. Adding another photo showing the base as well as the rest of the bush might be useful.

Comment: @MaryK, please include the information about "Queen Mary 2" in the question itself.  Comments are intended only for improving the question,not for useful details; they are ephemeral and can disappear at any time.